# Highlighting radio buttons after submit

Tags: javascript, html

how do you highlight radio button after submit?
Example code:

```
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return changeColor()" id="form">
    <h1>QUESTIONS</h1>

    <span>Question No. 1.)</span>What is your favorite food?<br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="yes" />A. Hi<br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />B. Hello <br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh<br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat<br />

    <span >Question No. 2.)</span>What is your favorite color?<br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi<br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello<br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh<br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat<br />

    <span >Question No. 2.)</span>What is your favorite color?<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat<br />

    <span >Question No. 2.)</span>What is your favorite color?<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh<br />
    <input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat<br />
```

after, submitting, radio button with value yes should be highlighted.how do i do that in javascipt?

Comment: have you tried anything? can you show `changeColor()`?

Comment: What do you mean with 'highlight'? The value? The button itself? I've never seen a 'highlighted' radio button..

Comment: oh i mean the text , not the radio button

Comment: When you submit the form to the server, it's going to reload the page, so you'd only see the highlighting for a brief second. I'd suggest highlighting it in whatever server-side language you're using to handle the form. Or are you suggesting you don't want to actually submit the form to the server, and instead just highlight the user's selections?

Answer (score 2):

You should use labels and the color can be done with css.

```js
function changeColor(form){
  form.classList.add("grade");  
  return false;
}
```

```css
.grade input[type="radio"][value="yes"]:checked + label {
  background-color: green;
}

.grade input[type="radio"][value="no"]:checked + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onsubmit="return changeColor(this)" id="form">
    <h1>QUESTIONS</h1>

    <span>Question No. 1.)</span>What is your favorite food?<br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="yes" id="one-a" /><label for="one-a">A. Hi</label> <br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  id="one-b" /><label for="one-b">B. Hello</label> <br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  id="one-c" /><label for="one-c">C. Ahh</label><br />
    <input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  id="one-d" /><label for="one-d">D. Kitkat</label><br />

    <span >Question No. 2.)</span>What is your favorite color?<br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  id="two-a" /><label for="two-a">A. Hi</label><br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="yes" id="two-b" /><label for="two-b">B. Hello</label><br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  id="two-c" /><label for="two-c">C. Ahh</label><br />
    <input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  id="two-d" /><label for="two-d">D. Kitkat</label><br />
  
    <input type="submit" value="grade" />
   
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it hard to locate the next sibling of the inputs, but the following works nicely:

Firstly, I've placed each input, with it's text, into separate div elements:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <h1>QUESTIONS</h1>

    <span>Question No. 1.)</span>What is your favorite food?</div>
    <div><input name="one" type="radio" value="yes" />A. Hi</div>
    <div><input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />B. Hello </div>
    <div><input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh</div>
    <div><input name="one" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat</div>

    <span >Question No. 2.)</span>What is your favorite color?</div>
    <div><input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi</div>
    <div><input name="two" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello</div>
    <div><input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh</div>
    <div><input name="two" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat</div>

    <span >Question No. 2.)</span>What is your favorite color?</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat</div>

    <span >Question No. 2.)</span>What is your favorite color?</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />A. Hi</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="yes"  />B. Hello</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />C. Ahh</div>
    <div><input name="three" type="radio" value="no"  />D. Kitkat</div>
    <div><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Next, using JavaScript, I've altered the forms 'onsubmit' function, and prevented it from submitting the forms information. I then iterate through all inputs in the form, checking whether their type is 'radio' and their value is 'yes', if so, the function changes the text color of the div that both the input and text lie within.

```
function form_color_change(e){
    // Prevent the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    // Gather collection of all inputs
    var inputs_collection = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var len = inputs_collection.length;
    // Iterate through inputs collection
    while(len--)
    {
        var input = inputs_collection[len];
        if(input.value == "yes" && input.type == "radio")
        {
            // If input type is 'radio' and value is 'true', color parent div text yellow
            input.parentNode.style.color = "#AAAA00";
        }
    }
}

// Change the forms default onsubmit event handler, to my own custom function (located above):
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
form.onsubmit = form_color_change;
```

This appears to work fine.

I had some trouble preventing the form from submitting using the 'return false' method in the inline 'onsubmit' event handler, hence the reason I've used JavaScript for this.

Here's a working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ShadeSpeed/407uc4ed/3/

I hope this helps!

Dan.